# Send data image from server to client

Tags: c, json, image, buffer, mongoose-web-server

i generate an image on my server and i would like to send image data to my client (that draw it on canvas)
I use Mongoose web server and function mg_printf_http_chunk() to send my data to my client (in json).
It works but it's very slow cause i construct in a loop a char* with data linebyline and strcat(). Is it possible to send an array by mongoose server and how ?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider sending the image in its raw binary format instead of some text-encoding scheme that has to be converted twice (on the server and on the client)?

Comment: [A `strcat` assembled text stream is *terrible*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). Don't do that. If you can send a device independent image blob, take that route. If not and you rather feel obligated/compelled/challenged to send a text stream, build it *without* atrocities like `strcat`.